# How to differentiate the names of each group of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I'm using formvalidation.io plugin to do the validation. By default, it validates the name of the radio buttons. But I can not do it that way. I need to know somehow / logic to differentiate each name of each radio buttons group.

Can someone help me?

EXAMPLE:

```
<div>
    <div id="perguntas">
        <label>1 - Pergunta 1</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="$pergunta->id" />
        <div id="respostas">
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="1" /> Male
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="2" /> Female
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="3" /> Other
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="mensagem[$pergunta->id]" rows="3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="perguntas">
        <label>2 - Pergunta 2</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="$pergunta->id" />
        <div id="respostas">
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="1" /> Male
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="2" /> Female
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="3" /> Other
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="mensagem[$pergunta->id]" rows="3" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="perguntas">
        <label>3 - Pergunta ...</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="$pergunta->id" />
        <div id="respostas">
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="1" /> Male
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="2" /> Female
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="3" /> Other
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="mensagem[$pergunta->id]" rows="3" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="perguntas">
        <label>16 - Pergunta 16</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="$pergunta->id" />
        <div id="respostas">
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="1" /> Male
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="2" /> Female
            <input type="radio" name="resposta[$pergunta->id]" value="3" /> Other
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="mensagem[$pergunta->id]" rows="3" />
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you create a JSFiddle of the same so we can help you. formvalidation library doesn't seem to be available online freely.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to uniquely identify each radio button in the form ? You can give "id" attribute to the radio buttons.